# Use FileContentResult with Unauthorized result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have API endpoint which returns `FileContentResult` when user is authorized to access file. I would like to return Unauthorized / 401 error when user has no access rights.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize("FileAccess")]
public FileContentResult GetFile(Guid fileId)
{
    if (!this.UserHasNoAccessToFile(fileId))
        return Unauthorized(); // does not work

    return File(...)

}
```

Looks, I can't simply return `Unauthorized()` while this can't be converted to `FileContentResult`.

Comment: Since you're using `FileContentResult` I'm assuming this is Core

Comment: Yep, it's Core - fixed questions tags.

Comment: Updated my answer if you're not on v2.1

Comment: @p3tch, works, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returning an `ActionResult<T>` instead.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize("FileAccess")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(401)]
public ActionResult<FileContentResult> GetFile(Guid fileId)
{
    if (!this.UserHasNoAccessToFile(fileId))
        return Unauthorized();

    return File(...)

}
```

[`ActionResult<T>` is new to ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#actionresultt-type), so you may need to update. If you don't want to update, simply return `IActionResult` and add the following attributes to your Action method

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileContentResult), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(401)]
```

The `ProducesResponseType` attributes are optional on either `ActionResult<T>` and `IActionResult`. They are [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#iactionresult-type) as they indicate what HTTP status codes can be expected from the Action, and in the case of `IActionResult`, what types can be returned (`ActionResult<T>` handles that for you)

---

And since this seems to be accessing files, you might want to make it an `async Task<ActionResult<FileContentResult>>` instead and access the file [asynchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) with the `await` keyword

```
public async Task<ActionResult<FileContentResult>> GetFile(Guid fileId)
{
    if (!this.UserHasNoAccessToFile(fileId))
        return Unauthorized();

    var bytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync("some path");
    return File(bytes, "contentType");
}
```